# How to change secret keys per environment while deploy, using Angular & Jenkins & Azure

Tags: angular, azure, jenkins, azure-web-app-service

I have several environments (dev, test, and prod) and I'm using some 3rd-party services, and for each environment, I have different access tokens/secret keys for these 3rd-party services.

I'm using Jenkins for CI/CD and the project uploaded as Azure App Service
Currently, in the deploy stage, I decide which key/token to use and it stored in assets. But the problem that assets are public folders, and it means that everyone can see all these keys.

Is there a way to hide them somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, since you are deploying to Azure, you should make use of the managed service in Azure such as [`Keyvault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#:%7E:text=Azure%20Key%20Vault%20is%20a,only%20authorized%20applications%20and%20users.) to store to your keys according to your environment, Also you could leverage [`AppSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common) in Azure Appservice to store some of the environment variables which has tight integration and more secured.